# Use POST to get data

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api

Currently, I'm using a POST-request to my Web API when I want to get data, rather then a GET-request, because the parameter that I'm sending, exceeds the URL-limit.

However, it's bad practice to use POST when you want to get data.

What is the correct way to do it when you have parameters that exceeds the URL limit and you must use POST instead of GET?

Comment: this exposes a greater underlying problem of the amount of details needed to be sent in order to get a response. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem

Comment: Also, this similar question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947414/using-post-as-a-workaround-for-the-url-character-limit

Comment: "However, it's bad practice to use POST when you want to get data." No, it isn't.

Comment: @EricStein: When you google, the majority says it is.

Comment: @Bryan I prefer to follow the HTTP spec, rather than following people who haven't read it but think they know what it says.

Comment: GET is *preferable* because it is both safe and idempotent. However, if GET does not work (as in your use case), the fallback is to use POST. If POST was not intended to support returning data, the HTTP spec would forbid a response body. It does not.

Comment: @EricStein: That's true. Can you link any resource regarding the HTTP spec about POSt?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3